# remove extra space in xamarin forms layout

Tags: c#, image, xamarin.forms, stacklayout

Hi i'm trying to place 2 image in xamarin forms using stackLayout.But it adds some space at the top of the form.I Used Blank Project.
my code is

```
<StackLayout>

    <Image Source="review.jpg"
               BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        WidthRequest="300"
        HeightRequest="100"
        VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        FlexLayout.Grow="1">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Navigate_review"/>
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>

    <Image Source="upload.jpg"
               BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        WidthRequest="320"
        HeightRequest="100"
        VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        FlexLayout.Grow="1">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Navigate_upload"/>
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
</StackLayout>
```

i am getting this output:

[Output Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYY0f.png)
[Output Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLnmQ.png)

It adds some extra space at the top of the page. how to set the layout to remove this space?

Comment: which white space you want to remove?

Comment: blue color present in before the  button

Comment: ,,can you clarifies your question? you said blue color to be removed? which blue color?

Comment: I modified my output image.I hope now you can understand .

Comment: Are you testing on emulator? Please test it on real devices. I think it will only cause this issues on emulators

Comment: thank you it's working on the device preview.But after converting into apk it looks like what present in the emulator right ?

Comment: Did it worked fine on real devices after installing  the apk?

Comment: i'm not telling the real device .it's a designer Area present in Xamarin .In designer area i'm getting correct output but not in the emulator .

Comment: Yes I have faced similar issue on emulator. It will no cause any problem in real devices.

Comment: I didn't convert into APK . I'm asking if i convert into APK it will show same as what i'm getting in the emulator right ?

Comment: If you convert it into apk and going to test it on a smartphone, it will never going to create any issue

Comment: Thank you so much @AndroDevil ... But what is the reason for this issue ?

Comment: Actually I dont know Anu priya.. May be the resolutions or something. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you are testing on emulators.Real devices will not show this issue I hope.

Comment: I don't want to hide the action bar.just want to hide blue color which is present after the action bar and before the button.I added Aspect like your code but still same i'm getting

Comment: Okey as I said above in comment section, Test it on real devices, Problem will be solved i guess

Answer (score 1):

The code you post does not have any issue.
I reckon your app is created with Tabbed template. If that is the case, the empty space at the top is actually the tab. As shown in this image.
[image: tabbed]

If you create a Blank project (not Tabbed nor MasterDetails), it will not have the empty spaces at the top. As shown in this image.
[image]

Comment: i created a Blank Project only . but i still adding that tab

Comment: i used the same code from your second image .and my emulator also same .but still getting same problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Margin** attribute to remove the excess space on top, bottom, right or left. Let's assume, if we using a table view and it produces the 20 pixel excess space on top of the display. So we can reduce that excess space by using

```
<TableView Margin="0,-20,0,0" >
<TableVie/>
```

**-20** using for reduce the excess 20pix

Answer (score 0):

**StackLayout** and **Grid** have default spacing of 6. On StackLayout you can set Spacing. For more details, you can refer to this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.stacklayout.spacing?view=xamarin-forms)

Try this snippet:

```
 <StackLayout
        Spacing="0">
        <Image
            Source="hintsicon"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            WidthRequest="300"
            HeightRequest="100"
            Aspect="Fill"
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                    Tapped="Navigate_review" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
        <Image
            Source="hintsicon"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            WidthRequest="320"
            HeightRequest="100"
            Aspect="Fill"
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                    Tapped="Navigate_upload" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: i added Spacing="0" but still same ..nothing is changed

Comment: Set `Aspect` to image view. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah i added Aspect.Still same problem i have . Is this depends on Emulator ?    i'm using Oreo 5554 emulator.

Comment: I don't think so. Try to uninstall the app and install a fresh one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using like below in your App.xaml.cs page:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```